# How to use class variables in a async.queue

Tags: node.js, async.js

im trying to use a async.queue in a class so i am able to use class variables. However if im trying to do so the variables are not defined. Is there any way to use it how expected?

```
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 'Hello World'
        this.q = async.queue(this.hello, 1)
    }

    hello(item, callback) {
        console.log(item)
        console.log(this.a) /* Not defined */
        callback()
    }

    start() {
        my_jobs = ['Foo', 'Bar',]
        my_jobs.forEach(element => {
            this.q.push(element)
        })
    }
}

my_class = new TestClass()
my_class.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var async = require('async');

class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 'Hello World';
        this.q = async.queue(this.hello.bind(this), 1); /* use .bind to keep context*/
    }

    hello(item, callback) {
        console.log(item);
        console.log(this.a); /* Defined: Hello World */
        callback();
    }

    start() {
        var my_jobs = ['Foo', 'Bar'];

        my_jobs.forEach(element => {
            this.q.push(element);
        });
    }
}

my_class = new TestClass();
my_class.start();
```